# Sending P2SH transaction with non-standard script

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction, p2sh

I'm trying to send transaction with script:

**ScriptSig**: `OP_PUSHDATA<Sig> OP_PUSHDATA<Data1> OP_PUSHDATA<Data2> OP_PUSHDATA<Data3>` `OP_PUSHDATA<RedeemScript>`

Since the data is less than 75 bytes in the raw transaction performed direct pushes.

RedeemScript: `2OP_DROP OP_2DROP OP_PUSHDATA<PubKey> OP_CHECKSIG`

RedeemScriptHash160 of `6d6d2202ada9884dbd1e8bd90968ba66256f017cd77d83595027f7929ae3537f98c92d4aac`=`738292fc46dd7af803bd56035d0988af96a31681`

**ScriptPubKey**: `OP_HASH160 <redeemScriptHash> OP_EQUAL`

But I get error when sending raw transaction:

> code=-26, message=16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Script
>   evaluated without error but finished with a false/empty top stack
>   element)

Could someone help to understand what is wrong with that script?
This this my transaction:

```
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

{
  "result": {
    "txid": "441cf52028ee0acc8b4076681c7fd46dad03501be62c6b0050ca59090fa52973",
    "hash": "dad2b4c56556b74d87243149ca3384ce04584d3bd8d21d80e291c4f9eed7e3f8",
    "version": 2,
    "size": 317,
    "vsize": 235,
    "locktime": 0,
    "vin": [
      {
        "txid": "ba1da008a017aef58fe929cc4afeb52cf77110fff5721aa9487ffb4d6f35152f",
        "vout": 0,
        "scriptSig": {
          "asm": "0014ac09dd336a6fc10034fc44dcb706855668921ce7 1f8b0800ffc1765400038d78055c545df3ff5d4a 1f8b0800ffc1765400038d78055c545df3ff5d4a 1f8b0800ffc1765400038d78055c545df3ff5d4a 6d6d2202ada9884dbd1e8bd90968ba66246f017cd77d83595027f7929ae3537f98c92d4a OP_CHECKSIG",
          "hex": "160014ac09dd336a6fc10034fc44dcb706855668921ce7141f8b0800ffc1765400038d78055c545df3ff5d4a141f8b0800ffc1765400038d78055c545df3ff5d4a141f8b0800ffc1765400038d78055c545df3ff5d4a246d6d2202ada9884dbd1e8bd90968ba66246f017cd77d83595027f7929ae3537f98c92d4aac"
        },
        "txinwitness": [
          "30450221009108d4e65a34fb50cd3283b6386a679f0dfc2b5fe97e3b3c3f6b8320814b3a2902204631daf2bb93605c9e079750092f304966b69fe28ce7701f4bc677714bca23af01",
          "02ada9884dbd1e8bd90968ba66256f017cd77d83595027f7929ae3537f98c92d4a"
        ],
        "sequence": 4294967295
      }
    ],
    "vout": [
      {
        "value": 0.31,
        "n": 0,
        "scriptPubKey": {
          "asm": "OP_HASH160 738292fc46dd7af803bd56035d0988af96a31681 OP_EQUAL",
          "hex": "a914738292fc46dd7af803bd56035d0988af96a3168187",
          "reqSigs": 1,
          "type": "scripthash",
          "addresses": [
            "2N3mz7o8v3YT4arXdQ5p8So6q3FUGjhUpEE"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "error": null,
  "id": "curltext"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the redeem script is executed, the stack looks like this (from top to bottom): `TRUE, Data3, Data2, Data1, Sig`. The `TRUE` on top of the stack comes from `OP_EQUAL`.

Now the redeem script runs and you drop the top three elements from the stack and then add `PubKey`, leaving you with `PubKey, Data1, Sig`. When `OP_CHECKSIG` runs now it uses `Data1` as Signature instead of `Sig` which makes it fail. At the end the stack is `FALSE, Sig`. The top element of the stack is `FALSE` which makes the transaction fail.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on this, if I change `OP_DROP` on `OP_2DROP` this should resolve my problem but not.

Comment: Did you make a completly new transaction? Because if you change `OP_DROP` to `OP_2DROP` the hash of the redeem script will be different and thus `OP_EQUAL` will return `FALSE` if you reuse your old `scriptPubKey` with the updated redeem script.

Comment: Yes, I updated it, but after I read your comment =). Also, I updated the post with new raw transaction.

Comment: I found one more mistake in my raw transaction. There was `OP_PUSHDATA<PubKey>` together with `OP_CHECKSIG`. You helped to resolve my issue but I have new. When I'm sending that raw I get error `mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature is found in scriptCode)`. Maybe you know what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry I also don't know what that means :( I suggest you make a new question with the new problem, maybe someone else knows whats wrong.